# Updating to 14.04.1 LTS broke netatalk mounts

Tags: server, upgrade, mount, backup

This morning I updated my Ubuntu Server installation from 14.04 to 14.04.1, using do-release-upgrade. Before the update, I was able to mount the shares on this server from my Mac, as well as use a share for backups. After the upgrade, connecting to the share causes the following to be displayed in syslog:

```
afpd[5695]: ===============================================================
afpd[5695]: INTERNAL ERROR: Signal 11 in pid 5695 (2.2.2)
afpd[5695]: ===============================================================
afpd[5695]: BACKTRACE: 3 stack frames:
afpd[5695]:  #0 /usr/sbin/afpd(netatalk_panic+0x1f) [0x7f1e96ac48bf]
afpd[5695]:  #1 /usr/sbin/afpd(+0x549bc) [0x7f1e96ac49bc]
afpd[5695]:  #2 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x37000) [0x7f1e953ef000]
```

My Macs syslog (OS X 10.9.4) displays the following:

```
kernel[0]: ASP_TCP CheckReqQueueSize: increasing req queue from 32 to 128 entries. so 0xffffff80318ea3b8 
kernel[0]: ASP_TCP CancelOneRequest: cancelling slot 2 error 89 reqID 4 flags 0x9 afpCmd 0x13 so 0xffffff80318ea3b8
NetAuthSysAgent[13902]: afp_sendmsg:  sendmsg failed 0xffffffff errno = 89 
NetAuthSysAgent[13902]: afp_sendmsg:  sendmsg failed 0xffffffff errno = 32 
NetAuthSysAgent[13902]: ERROR: AFP_OpenSession - Login failed with 89
```

The kernel[0] errors are also thrown when backupd attempts to mount the share for a scheduled backup, so they appear to be related, though I can't fathom what they mean.

Any ideas? I've completely erased netatalk with `apt-get remove --purge netatalk` and re-installed it, as well as rebooting the server multiple times, with the same errors displayed. Also, SMB shares still work fine, but obviously SMB won't work for Time Machine backups.

Answer (score 5):

It's a bug in libpam-smbpass. You can get rid of it, the only thing it does is that it forces sync between the samba and unix password on login:

```
sudo apt-get remove libpam-smbpass
sudo service netatalk restart
```

And you're golden again.